# Retirar options do select com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, option

Estou tentando tirar todos os `option's` de um select que tenho, mas já usei de tudo quanto é código do `jQuery` mas eles não saem. Estou fazendo um filtro aonde a pessoa vai selecionar uma **cidade** e após selecionar o jQuery faz uma requisição `Ajax` para o `PHP` que retorna as cidades para fazer alguns options de um segundo `select`. Isso ele faz normalmente, mas caso a pessoa esteja no terceiro `select` e mude o primeiro por exemplo (cidade) então ele tem que reiniciar os outros filtros, zerando os `option's` do segundo e terceiro, e é isso que não estou conseguindo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei:

```
$("#profissionalFiltro").find('option:not(:first)').remove();

$("#profissionalFiltro option").remove();

$("#profissionalFiltro").empty();
```

Mas nenhum resolveu.

Answer (score 4):

A ultima linha é pra funcionar. Veja o exemplo

```
<select id="profissionalFiltro">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
<button id="limpar">Limpar</button>

$("#limpar").click(function(event) {
    $("#profissionalFiltro").empty();
    //$("#profissionalFiltro option").remove(); //essa tambem funciona
});
```

Deve ter algum outro problema que não está funcionando

https://jsfiddle.net/ht4oj8r0/1/

Answer (score 1):

Basta 'limpar' o html do select, da seguinte forma:

```
$("#profissionalFiltro").html('');
```

Ou assim:

```
$("#profissionalFiltro").html('<option value="">Selecione</option>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que no código a primeira linha tenha um valor

```
<select id="profissionalFiltro">
    <option value="0">Selecione um "opção"</option>
    <option>Opção 1</option>
    <option>Opção 2</option>
    <option>Opção 3</option>
</select>
```

no js você pode colocar

```
$("#profissionalFiltro").val("0");
$('#profissionalFiltro option:not(:selected)').remove();
```